# Getting context of parent function-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-callback

I have following script

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var str="";
          var className="";
          $(".question_one_select").click(function(){

                  //if($(this).find(':radio').is(":disabled")==false){
                    //call ajax here
                    val=$(this).find(':radio').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{Request::root()}}/myprofile/ajax/myquiz?id="+val,
                        context: document.body
                        }).done(function(data) {
                                //$( this ).addClass( "done" );
                                if(data.trim()==2){
                                    alert("Please , login and answer quiz correctly to win exciting prizes");
                                }

                                else if(data.trim()==1){
                                    //append correct answer string
                                     alert("Correct answer !! you earned some points");
                                    $(this).closest('.question_title').find('.correct').show();
                                     //this is not working

                                }

                                else {
                                    alert("Oops!! wrong answer , better luck next time");

                                }

                            }); 
                    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked',true);
                    $(this).closest('.question_title').find(':radio').remove();
                    //alert(className);



             });
});
  </script>
```

**Problem :** when i receive a callback 'done' from ajax i need to make some changes on parent div i was trying to call

```
$(this).closest('.question_title').find('.correct').show();
```

where `$(this)` should be context of   `$(".question_one_select").click(function(){`

Comment: change `context: document.body` to `context: this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` option in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is used to specify the context that should be used in the callback methods.

Since you are passing the context as document.body to the ajax call, `this` inside the callback will refer to the `document.body` object. So change that to `this`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = "";
    var className = "";
    $(".question_one_select").click(function () {

        //if($(this).find(':radio').is(":disabled")==false){
        //call ajax here
        val = $(this).find(':radio').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{Request::root()}}/myprofile/ajax/myquiz?id=" + val,
            context: this
        }).done(function (data) {
            //$( this ).addClass( "done" );
            if (data.trim() == 2) {
                alert("Please , login and answer quiz correctly to win exciting prizes");
            } else if (data.trim() == 1) {
                //append correct answer string
                alert("Correct answer !! you earned some points");
                var className = ".correct";
                $(this).closest('.question_title').find(className).show();
                //this didnt refer to  $(".question_one_select")



            } else {
                alert("Oops!! wrong answer , better luck next time");

            }

        });
        $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('.question_title').find(':radio').remove();
        alert(className);
        //(this).closest('.question_title').find(className).show();


    });
});
```